# c# WMPLib Shuffle play MP3 files in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building an MP3 player in c# winforms using WMPLib. I have code which allows the user to upload MP3 files into listbox1. I want the user to be able to shuffle the items in listbox1 so that a random item (MP3) will play. Currently, I have code which shuffles the items in listbox1, but the item in the initial index plays. I hope this makes sense.

**Here is my code for the user to upload their files.**

```
 private void uploadSongs()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                filelist.Items.Add(files[i]);

            }

        }

    }
```

**Here is the code to shuffle the listbox1 items:**

```
   private void shuffleBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListBox.ObjectCollection list = fielist.Items;
        Random random = new Random();
        int w = list.Count;
        filelist.BeginUpdate();

        while (w > 1)
        {
            w--;
            int u = random.Next(w + 1);
            object value = list[u];
            list[u] = list[w];
            list[w] = value;
        }

        filelist.EndUpdate();
        filelist.Invalidate();

    }
```

***I have added the following code for the playlist to the shuffleBttn_Click***

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = WMPPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");
        WMPLib.IWMPMedia media;
        foreach (object item in filelist.Items)
        {
            media = WMPPlayer.newMedia((string)item);
            playlist.appendItem(media);
        }
        WMPPlayer.currentPlaylist = playlist;
        WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: Note: I am using "filelist" rather than listbox1.

Answer (score 0):

Step into your code in VS debugger you will find the value of `listBox1.SelectedIndex` is unchanged in the while loop. So you end up setting `WMPPlayer.URL` multiple times with the same item in the list.

Consider creating a playlist.

```
...
//remove these 2 lines that cause the problem
//value = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
//WMPPlayer.URL = filepaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
...
listBox1.EndUpdate();
listBox1.Invalidate();

//after shuffling the items in listbox, create a playlist from the listbox

WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = WMPPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");
WMPLib.IWMPMedia media;
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
{
    media = WMPPlayer.newMedia((string)item);
    playlist.appendItem(media);
}    
WMPPlayer.currentPlaylist = playlist;
WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

**Edit: The complete code that works on my device**

```
    private void uploadSongs(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var files = openFileDialog1.FileNames; //I also changed this line
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                filelist.Items.Add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void shuffleBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox.ObjectCollection list = filelist.Items;
        Random random = new Random();
        int w = list.Count;
        filelist.BeginUpdate();

        while (w > 1)
        {
            w--;
            int u = random.Next(w + 1);
            object value = list[u];
            list[u] = list[w];
            list[w] = value;
        }

        filelist.EndUpdate();
        filelist.Invalidate();

        WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = WMPPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");
        WMPLib.IWMPMedia media;
        foreach (object item in filelist.Items)
        {
            media = WMPPlayer.newMedia((string)item);
            playlist.appendItem(media);
        }
        WMPPlayer.currentPlaylist = playlist;
        WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
     }
```

Comment: I have implemented the above code, but I am still running into the same issue. The song in the original index still plays. @kennyzx

Comment: what is the code inside the shuffle_button_click now? Can u post it?

Comment: I have posted the recommended changes to the shuffleBttn_Click @kennyzx

Comment: What is the type of filelist? and filelist is not randomized, right? Also, remember to remove those 2 lines as I mentioned at the beginning of the code sample.

Comment: Forgot to edit changes. Listbox1 was just changed to filelist. It's just a listbox, and it has not been randomized prior to shuffle click. @kennyzx

Comment: It works perfectly on my side. See my complete code.